# Why is $(this) value different in the first click and the second click on a table click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a table like this:

```
<table ng-click="tableClick($event)" id="myTable"></table>
```

And a function like this:

```
$scope.tableClick = function($event) {

    $('#myTable').find('tr').click( function($event) {
        $scope.clickedRow = $(this).index();
    });

    $state.go('somePage', {
        pageId : $scope.data[$scope.clickedRow].id
    });
};
```

The function basically gets the clicked row number and uses that information to find correct id value in the data. With that id value it navigates to another page.

When clicked for the first time I debug the code and it does not get inside the click function and the value of $(this) on the debug screen is:

```
$get.Scope.$new.$$childScopeClass$$childHead: null$$childScopeClass: null$$childTail: null$$listenerCount: Object$$listeners: Object$$nextSibling: null$$prevSibling: $get.Scope.$new.$$childScopeClass$$watchers: null$id: "008"$parent: $get.Scope.$new.$$childScopeClasssummary: Array[7]tableClick: function ($event) {this: $get.Scope.$new.$$childScopeClass__proto__: $get.Scope.$new.$$childScopeClass]
```

And I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
at Scope.$scope.tableClick (http://localhost:9001/scripts/controllers/summary.js:129:53)
at Parser.functionCall (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10847:21)
at ngEventDirectives.(anonymous function).compile.element.on.callback (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/angular/angular.js:19136:17)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12702:28)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12800:23)
at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/angular/angular.js:19141:23)
at HTMLTableElement.x.event.dispatch (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/iids/dist/iidx/components/jquery/jquery.min.js:5:14129)
at HTMLTableElement.x.event.add.v.handle (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/iids/dist/iidx/components/jquery/jquery.min.js:5:10873)
```

When it is clicked after the first time it actually returns the row, and its index number.

Why doesn't $(this) loads the table row for the first time? How can I load it?

Comment: Why u use angular by jQuery-way ? Why u cant call func from ng-click ?

Comment: You should better create a directive

Comment: It seems a rather complicated way of achieving your goal? why not use an ng-repeat such as (thing in things) in your table then an ng-click="findRow(thing.id)" then in your controller findRow = function(thing.id) and use $location path to navigate to the page?

Comment: @Jax700303 My company makes me use datatables.js for creating tables, I don't  think(know) if I can use it with repeater.